# How to improve communication between manager and employee to improve productivity?

Tags: professionalism, communication, email, productivity, teamwork

This is not my situation, but something I am witnessing and was asked to help with. So, suppose that I lead a small team. I communicate and provide details on tasks to team members via email.

One of the team members does not respond promptly (i.e. same day) to emails, so it is unclear where he is on the tasks. He does not provide regular status updates when they are requested (also by email). And he does not show initiative in tackling new tasks, or improving the quality of the output from the assigned tasks.

Unless specifically given very concrete tasks and deadlines, he basically 'sits on his hands' and waits for work to find him. As I see it, he does the absolute minimum and avoids challenge. If I had no work for him for 6 months, I have reason to believe that I would not hear a word from him for 6 months. Overall, he lacks in communication skills, efficiency, and initiative that as a professional I would expect to come 'standard' with experienced professional employees.

In contrast, other team members typically respond to emails in a more timely manner, provide their own perspectives on the task, and generally bring all of their knowledge and experience to the table when approaching a task or resolving an issue. This suggests that it's not *just me* -- otherwise the lacking performance would have been more widespread.

The employee in question seems to have an OK attitude in general and is not a "troublemaker". He just does not seem to put in any more effort than necessary to complete the immediate task at hand -- but not an inch more.

Because this individual's time on task for any more or less advanced tasks has exceeded the most liberal estimates and resulted in weeks taken up by what was expected to be completed in days, over time the complexity of tasks relegated to him has decreased, in efforts to salvage time while adding at least some value to the team.

**Overall, there is a disconnect in expectations around communication and performance.** However, I am unsure about (a) where to start, and (b) how to discuss these topics in a way that would not make the person feel singled out and antagonize him.

As someone who is ultimately responsible for the team's performance I want to remedy the situation. I am also ready and willing to change my own approach to working with this employee, as long as things improve.

I allow the possibility that this individual's lacking performance may be due in part to something *I* am either doing wrong or am not doing at all. I am just having trouble figuring out what that is...since he appears to be the only one impacted by whatever I may be doing wrong or not doing.

I want to avoid conflict but I also want things to change for the better, and fast. Firing him (or at least being able to exercise this option) may have been the preferred solution, but owing to some other circumstances is not an option.

**What action can the Team Lead take in order to correct the situation?**

What would help set the employee on a course of improving the skills that seem lacking, without putting him on the spot too much?

**My hunch is to begin by addressing communication issues.** Otherwise efforts aimed at directly improving productivity and quality would likely be futile.

Note, Some team members are local and some remote; the individual in question is currently remote.

*Note, based on feedback received this question has been completely revised from the earlier version which received the downvotes.*

Comment: linking a similar question for extra reference https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96696/unproductive-subordinate-missing-deadlines-due-to-health-conditions-and-problems

Comment: Based on feedback received this question has been completely revised from the earlier version which received the downvotes. I hope this version works better and can receive some responses. Thank you.

Comment: I have fully revised this question based on the feedback received. It would be great if someone added their vote to reopen the question...I asked it for a reason, guys.

Comment: @AnneDaunted I believe always, or at least in the current role. The issue has been glossed over, with not enough incentive or impetus for change. My guess is that the neglect conveyed the impression that this is "good enough," and if this works, why improve. The deficiency in skill is definitely there, and there is evidence that skills have not been improving at the rate that would make the individual's productivity on par with expectations.There has been some (very) gradual improvement though. Being remote probably doesn't help, but that is not currently fixable.

Comment: @AnneDaunted You may be right, it appears self-esteem issues may be in play here. If so, the question is how to reverse this framework and set him on the path of gradual 'restoration' of his self esteem? Everyone can perform higher than their typical level, it's an issue of motivation and self-belief. Goal-setting literature (e.g. Carol Dweck's) talks about this...maybe I need to start there. As one tactic, setting intermediate achievable goals and requeting status on those may be a way to go, since this should shift the focus on instances of success rather than failure (e.g.missing deadline).

Comment: @AnneDaunted Can you recommend other ways to lift someone's self-esteem? I don't want to go the route of frequent generic unconditional praise (e.g. praising effort unless it is followed by result), as the goal is to actually improve his performance, not just self-perception and not just effort ;) He seems capable of expending substantial effort, it's the efficiency and effectiveness that seem to lag. So I am chiefly interested in recommendations that have been proven to increase and sustain performance.

Answer (score 1):

### Organisation tools.

With people like that, everything must be simple and straightforward. I've had a habit of using tools such as trello, TFS, or even a simple whiteboard with post it notes on it (some of these are rather specific for programming tasks, but the idea stands).

The idea is that anyone and every one can always check on who is doing what, and what is the due date for each task ( or estimated time). This promotes a slightly competitive atmosphere, or at least pushes employees to stay on the team standard work rate.

Once an employee has finished a task it is appears straght away, and urges said employee to go look for something else to do.

Another advantage of such a tool is to record performance. If this employee consistently under performs compared to what is expected, you can confront him with written and precise information concerning what the problem is and what is expected

Comment: Very cool idea. I will consider exploring what we have in terms of such tools and experimenting.